# Problema al guardar contraseñas en php

Tags: php, mysql

Tengo un formulario donde se pueden editar los datos del usuario , las contraseñas están encriptadas en md5, imaginaos que la contraseña es 12345 y edito el perfil pero la contraseña no, entonces cuando quiero iniciar sesión no vale poner la contraseña sino que tengo que poner 12345 en md5, no se como puedo solucionarlo , esto solo pasa si no se cambia la contraseña porque cuando la modifico en vez 12345 es abcd pues esta se guarda en md5 pero puedo hacer login igualment, a lo mejor debería verificar si sea cambiado la contraseña o algo así.

````
<div class="body">
    <h2><?php echo $lang['edit_user'] ?></h2>
    <?php 
        if(isset($_SESSION['edit']))
        {
            echo $_SESSION['edit'];
            unset($_SESSION['edit']);
        }

        if (isset($_GET['id']) && !empty($_GET['id'])) {
            $id = $_GET['id'];

            $tbl_name = 'tbl_usuarios';
            $where = "id='$id'";

            $query = $obj->select_data($tbl_name,$where);
            $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);
            if($res==true)
            {
                $count_rows = $obj->num_rows($res);
                if($count_rows==1)
                {
                    $row = $obj->fetch_data($res);
                    $nom_com = $row['nom_com'];
                    $DNI = $row['DNI'];
                    $Direccion = $row['Direccion'];
                    $tel = $row['tel'];
                    $email = $row['email'];
                    $contra = $row['contra'];
                    $activado = $row['activado'];
                }
            }
        }
        else
        {
            header('location:'.SITEURL.'admin/index.php?page=users');
        }
    ?>
    <form method="post" action="">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label"><?php echo $lang['nom_com'] ?></span>
            <input class="half" type="text" name="nom_com" value="<?php echo $nom_com; ?>" required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label"><?php echo $lang['DNI'] ?></span>
            <input class="half" type="text" name="DNI" pattern="[0-9]{8}[A-Za-z]{1}" value="<?php echo $DNI; ?>" required="true" disabled>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label"><?php echo $lang['dire'] ?></span>
            <textarea class="half" name="Direccion"><?php echo $Direccion; ?></textarea>
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label"><?php echo $lang['tel'] ?></span>
            <input class="half" type="tel" name="tel"   value="<?php echo $tel; ?>"  required="true">
        </div>
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label"><?php echo $lang['email'] ?></span>
            <input class="half" type="email" name="email" value="<?php echo $email; ?>" required="true">
        </div>

        

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label"><?php echo $lang['contra'] ?></span>
            <input class="half" type="password" name="contra" value="<?php echo $contra; ?>" required="true">
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label"><?php echo $lang['activado'] ?></span>
            <input <?php if($activado=='Yes'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> type="radio" name="activado" value="Yes"> <?php echo $lang['si'] ?> 
            <input <?php if($activado=='No'){echo "checked='checked'";} ?> type="radio" name="activado" value="No"> <?php echo $lang['no'] ?>
        </div>

        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-label">
                <input type="hidden" name="id" value="<?php echo $id; ?>">
                <input class="btn-primary btn-sm" type="submit" name="submit" value="<?php echo $lang['edit_user'] ?>">
                <button type="button" class="btn-volver btn-sm" onclick="history.back()"><?php echo $lang['volver'] ?></button>
            </span>
        </div>
        <br>
    </form>

    <?php 
        if(isset($_POST['submit']))
        {
            $id = $_POST['id'];
            $nom_com = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['nom_com']);
            $DNI = $row['DNI'];
            $Direccion = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['Direccion']);
            $tel = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['tel']);
            $email = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['email']);
            $contra = md5($obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['contra']));
            $activado = $_POST['activado'];
            $created_at = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');

            $data = "
            nom_com='$nom_com',
                DNI='$DNI',
                Direccion='$Direccion',
                tel='$tel',
                contra='$contra',
                activado='$activado',
                created_at='$created_at'
            ";
            $tbl_name='tbl_usuarios';
            $where = "id='$id'";
            $query = $obj->update_data($tbl_name,$data,$where);
            $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);
            //DAR DE BAJA 
            
            
            if($res==true)
            {   
            if($activado=='No'){
                $_SESSION['login'] = "<div class='success'>".$lang['baja']."</div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'usu/index.php?page=logout');
            }else{
                $_SESSION['edit'] = "<div class='success'>".$lang['edit_bien']."</div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'usu/index.php?page=perfil');
            }
            }
            else
            {
                $_SESSION['edit'] = "<div class='error'>".$lang['edit_mal']."</div>";
                header('location:'.SITEURL.'usu/index.php?page=edit_perfil&id='.$id);
            }
        }
    ?>
</div>```
[![introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí][1]][1]
EDITO:LOGIN.PHP
```
        <?php 
            if(isset($_POST['submit']))
            {
                
                $uwu = $obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['DNI']);
                $password = md5($obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['contra']));
                
                $tbl_name = "tbl_usuarios";
                $where = "DNI='$uwu' && contra='$password'";
                
                
                $query = $obj->select_data($tbl_name,$where);
                
                $res = $obj->execute_query($conn,$query);
                $count_rows = $obj->num_rows($res);
                if($count_rows>0)
                {
                    
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "<div class='success'>".$lang['se_bi'].".</div>";
                    $_SESSION['user'] = $uwu;
                    header('location:'.SITEURL.'usu/');
                }
                else
                {
                    $_SESSION['login'] = "<div class='error'>".$lang['se_mal']."</div>";
                    header('location:'.SITEURL.'usu/login.php');
                }
            }
        
        ?>
    </div>
</body>
</html>
````

Lo voy a intentar aclarar mejor, yo cuando edito el usuario puedo cambiar todos los campos , el problema es que cuando creas un usuario la contraseña se encripta en md5 y se guarda asi en la base de datos , entonces al editar el perfil no muestra la contraseña encriptada , entonces si no la cambias la contraseña encriptada vuelve a encriptarse, pero si la contraseña la cambio por otra esta se encripta y puedo utilizarla en el login .

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Creo entender, que estás ingresando la contraseña, pero al ingresar esta, no la comparas con el md5 en la base de datos. O si la comparas, pero no te da un true como debería... es eso ?

Comment: Puedes agregar el código de inicio de sesión

Comment: ¿Hay algún motivo que **justifique** el uso de MD5? El [Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.md5.php) es claro con respecto a esta función: ***Advertencia**: No se recomienda utilizar esta función para contraseñas seguras debido a la naturaleza rápida de este algoritmo de «hashing». Véase las [Preguntas más frecuentes de «hash» de contraseñas](https://www.php.net/manual/es/faq.passwords.php#faq.passwords.fasthash) para más detalles y el empleo de mejores prácticas.* Por tanto, si es posible, evita el uso de MD5.

Comment: Es una prueba que estoy haciendo.

Answer (score 0):

Por lo que entendí, la contraseña la guardas en MD5 por lo cual cuando inicias sesión debes convertir el texto introducido del campo de contraseña a MD5, tal cual como lo haces al registrar el usuario.

```
$contra = md5($obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['contra']));
```

Adicionalmente te recomiendo que utilices otros métodos de cifrado para el uso de contraseñas en PHP, por ejemplo `password_hash`, ya que MD5 se puede descifrar fácilmente.

Comment: No es eso lo que hace durante el submit ?? -> `$contra = md5($obj->sanitize($conn,$_POST['contra']));`

Comment: @Excorpion Si pero al editar el usuario y por lo que dice se deduce que no lo hace para el inicio de sesión